# Find a specific word algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, tree

i try to build an algorithm to find a forbidden word which has 4 characters.
My assignment is to call the function sendMessage() as rarely as possible.

here are some details about the sendMessage() Function:
bool sendMessage(std::string message)
The message can be a maximum of 10,000 characters long and consist only of lowercase letters from 'a' to 'z'.
The function returns true if the message has been censored; otherwise, it returns false.

The way i wanted to solve this problem is that i just create random words with 4 characters and put them all together in a string with 10000 characters (2500 words * 4 characters each).
After that i look if the sendMessage() Function returns true and if that is the case, i apply something like a Tree Search where i divide the message into 2 parts, see if it returns true on one of these, if yes devide again into 2 parts and so on.

My problem now is that my program doesn't find the forbidden word.
Here is my Code:

```
#include "zensur.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility> // for std::pair

std::pair<std::string, std::string> splitString(const std::string& inputString) {
    // Determine the length of the string
    size_t length = inputString.length();

    // Check if the length is even or odd
    if (length % 2 == 0) {
        // If the length is even, split the string into two halves
        size_t middle = length / 2;

        std::string part1 = inputString.substr(0, middle);
        std::string part2 = inputString.substr(middle);

        return std::make_pair(part1, part2);
    }
    else {
        // If the length is odd, split the string so that the first part has an additional character
        size_t middle = length / 2;

        std::string part1 = inputString.substr(0, middle + 1);
        std::string part2 = inputString.substr(middle + 1);

        return std::make_pair(part1, part2);
    }
}

std::string findBannedWord() {
    const int wordLength = 4;
    std::string concatenatedWords;

    for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; ++a) {
        for (char b = 'a'; b <= 'z'; ++b) {
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
                for (char d = 'a'; d <= 'z'; ++d) {

                    // make a potential word
                    std::string potentialWord = { a, b, c, d }; 

                    
                    if (concatenatedWords.length() < (10000 - wordLength)) {    
                        // put 2500 potential words together to a concatenated Word
                        concatenatedWords += potentialWord;
                    }

                    // if the concatenated Word is 10000 long (2500*4) then look if the forbidden word is in it
                    if (concatenatedWords.length() == 10000) {  
                        if (sendMessage(concatenatedWords)) {   

                        // if it is in it then apply something like a tree structure to find it.
                            while (true) {
                                // split it into 2 substrings
                                std::pair<std::string, std::string> innerParts = splitString(concatenatedWords);    

                                // if it is in the first substring
                                if (sendMessage(innerParts.first)) {                
                                    concatenatedWords = innerParts.first;
                                    continue;
                                }

                                // if it is in the second substring
                                else if (sendMessage(innerParts.second)) {            
                                    concatenatedWords = innerParts.second;
                                    continue;
                                }

                                // if it is in none of those substrings then look at the end of first substring and beginning of second substring combined
                                else {                                              
                                    size_t length = innerParts.first.length();
                                    std::string endString = innerParts.first.substr(length - 4);
                                    std::string startString = innerParts.second.substr(0, 4);

                                    // put the end of first substring and beginning of second  
                                    // substring together
                                    std::string realString = endString + startString;   
    
                                    // go through all 5 possibilitys
                                    for (int i = 0; i < ((realString.length() - wordLength) + 1); ++i) {        
                                        std::string substring = realString.substr(i, wordLength);

                                        // if we found the forbidden word return it
                                        if (sendMessage(substring)) {       
                                            return substring;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // if forbidden word is not in there clear concatenatedWords and try again
                        concatenatedWords = ""; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ""; // return empty string if word is not found
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone can help me find the mistake in my code.
I personally think my error is somewhere in this section:

```
 // if it is in none of those substrings then look at the end of first substring and beginning of second substring combined
else {                                             
    size_t length = innerParts.first.length();
    std::string endString = innerParts.first.substr(length - 4);
    std::string startString = innerParts.second.substr(0, 4);

    // put the end of first substring and beginning of second substring together
    std::string realString = endString + startString;       

    // go through all 5 possibilitys
    for (int i = 0; i < ((realString.length() - wordLength) + 1); ++i) {        
        std::string substring = realString.substr(i, wordLength);

        / if we found the forbidden word return it
        if (sendMessage(substring)) {       /
            return substring;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I would be very grateful if someone can help me find the mistake in my code* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: "i just create random words" That's your problem right here. You want to do something a bit smarter than that. Quite a bit smarter actually.

Comment: Don't create random words if you want to successfully debug your program.  Instead use *known*, hard-coded words that you know triggers the failure.  Also don't start off with large data such as 10,000 characters.  If your program doesn't work with 20 or 30 character strings, it isn't going to work with 10,000 characters.

Comment: dont use random words. If you are unluck they are all `aaaaaaaaaaaaa.....` and you'll never find a forbidden word when it is eg `foo`

Comment: (1) Your `concatenatedWords` contains one huge word, 10000 characters long. How do you expect that to work? (2) You have 456976 possible words to test. Every 2000 (not 2500) of them will fit into a string of length 9999 (not 10000). That’s at most 229 calls of `sendMessage()` to find out which batch of 2000 words the forbidden one is in. (3) Once you find the problematic message, you need to split it until you locate the exact word. That would be around 11 binary splits, in the worst case with 2 attempts per split, mostly, so around 20 extra calls. So in <250 calls you should get the word.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Actually sending one huge 10000-characters word lets you find the answer *way* faster than sending batches of separated 4-letter words.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek <250 calls of  `sendMessage()` would be okay for my case. Can you tell me where the error is in my Code. I dont get any error Message. The Program just does not find the word i am looking for.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI what do you suggest? <250 calls of `sendMessage()` would be enough for me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem is i am looking for a word that i don't know. It does not have to be a bad word. It could be the word "ever". I know for sure that the function `sendMessage()` can handle a string with a maximum of 10000 characters.

Comment: Let's say you send a message of 10000 characters *such that no 4-letter word occurs twice in it*, and that message is flagged as having a bad word. Do you know what to do next? Do you know how to generate such messages?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI i would probably stay with my randomWord. I would then just do `concatenatedWords.find(randomWord)` and if it already contains the word just don't add it to my concatenatedWords. After the sendMessage(concatenatedWords) returns true i would go on and do the "Binary Search" like in my Code above.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI How so? What if `abcd` is the forbidden word, but both `xabcd` and `abcdy` are allowed? I can’t see any rule in the task specification about _all substrings_ of each word being checked. This makes it unclear _why_ a concatenation of “words” without spaces should trigger the “censorship”. A real-life example: In Czech, _kurtosis_ (the term from statistics) is _špičatost_. While _špičatost_ is uncontroversial (and means _pointiness_ too), a 4-letter substring (1-based) from character 2 through character 5 is a forbidden word. That said, why is the concatenation supposed to work?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Can you see any rule that allows a separator between words in a message? "The message can be a maximum of 10,000 characters long and consist only of lowercase letters from 'a' to 'z'."  This assignment is *probably* not about finding forbidden sequences of letters between spaces. If it were about that, it would be utterly pointless, boring and trivial.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You’re right. It looks like the “any substring” interpretation makes more sense. In that case I’d probably keep building a `std::set` of all 4-letter substrings encountered and only add a letter to the “message” if the three last letters plus the “candidate” letter were _not_ in the `std::set` yet. With only 456976 4-letter substrings, this is perfectly doable. One could instead build an Aho-Corasick automaton on the go and use it the same way as the `std::set` (for better asymptotic complexity), but only the number of `sendMessage()` calls matters, so … meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've implemented binary search, which is a good idea.

There are a few issues though:

- The condition to extend `concatenatedWords` with four more letters is not good:

  ```
  if (concatenatedWords.length() < (10000 - wordLength)) {
  ```

  This means that when the length of `concatenatedWords` is 9996 no word will be added to it, and thus the following condition will *never* be true:

  ```
  else if (concatenatedWords.length() == 10000) {
  ```

  ...meaning that the binary search will never be performed.

  The correction is that you should also add the word when there is equality in that first `if` condition. So do:

  ```
  if (concatenatedWords.length() <= (10000 - wordLength)) { // fix
  ```
- In the binary search part, in the special case where the word is neither found in the left nor the right partition, you have this expression:

  ```
  innerParts.first.substr(length - 4)
  ```

  This expression will raise an error when `innerParts.first` has a size that is less than 4, which is well possible. I could reproduce it by testing with the banned word "zzyx". This should be corrected to:

  ```
  innerParts.first.substr(length > 3 ? length - 4 : 0)
  ```

  but see next point.
- Not a problem, but in that special case where the banned word is being cut by the partitioning, you only need to treat 3 cases, not 5. So instead of `length - 4`, you only need `length - 3`, and similarly, only `substr(0, 3)` and not `substr(0, 4)`.
- Related to the above: you have the constant `wordLength`, but you don't use it consistently, like for instance in determining the size of the substrings in the above mentioned case.
- Since the number of 4 letter words is not a multiple of 10000, you might end up<sup>*</sup> with a remainder when exiting the four nested loops without success. It would then be necessary to find the banned word in that remaining string. So I would replace the `return "";` at the very end with another execution of the binary search algorithm. That brings me to the following point.

  <sub><sup>*</sup> I am not entirely sure this case will actually happen, because the way you build the string, there will be several occurrences of the same word. For instance, in the very first chunk, the word `aaaa` will occur at index 0, index 1 and index 2, because that chunk starts with `aaaaaaabaaac`. Similarly `zzzz` will appear in the concatenation of `yzzz` and `zaaa`.</sub>
- Not a problem, but the code is rather deeply nested. This should be an opportunity to separate some code into a new function. The obvious candidate for this is the binary search algorithm. This will also make it easy to call it again at the very end in case there was no match in the chunks of 10000 characters.

This leads to the following code:

```
const int wordLength = 4; // Used in the two functions below

// Isolate the binary search logic in a separate function
std::string binarySearch(std::string concatenatedWords) {
    while (true) {
        // split it into 2 substrings
        std::pair<std::string, std::string> innerParts = splitString(concatenatedWords);
        // if it is in the first substring
        if (sendMessage(innerParts.first)) {                
            concatenatedWords = innerParts.first;
            continue;
        }
        // if it is in the second substring
        if (sendMessage(innerParts.second)) {            
            concatenatedWords = innerParts.second;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            size_t length = innerParts.first.length();
            // Fix to avoid a negative argument in substr. 
            // Fix to use the wordLength constant.
            std::string endString = innerParts.first.substr(length >= wordLength
 ? length - wordLength + 1 : 0);
            std::string startString = innerParts.second.substr(0, wordLength - 1);
    
            std::string realString = endString + startString;   

            // Fix to use the wordLength constant
            for (int i = 0; i < ((realString.length() - wordLength) + 1); ++i) {        
                std::string substring = realString.substr(i, 4);
                if (sendMessage(substring)) {       
                    return substring;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}


std::string findBannedWord() {
    std::string concatenatedWords;

    for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; ++a) {
        for (char b = 'a'; b <= 'z'; ++b) {
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
                for (char d = 'a'; d <= 'z'; ++d) {
                    std::string potentialWord = { a, b, c, d };
                    // Fixed comparison:
                    if (concatenatedWords.length() <= (10000 - wordLength)) {
                        concatenatedWords += potentialWord;
                    }
                    else if (concatenatedWords.length() == 10000) {
                        if (sendMessage(concatenatedWords)) {
                            return binarySearch(concatenatedWords);
                        }
                        concatenatedWords = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Also look in the "left over"
    return binarySearch(concatenatedWords); 
}
```

There is room for optimisation because it is possible to use shorter strings. Potentially at every single index you could have a new 4-letter word starting. Almost every 4-letter word now appears multiple times in your concatenated string, and this is a waste of space, leading to a few more calls of the `sendMessage` function in the worst case than might be strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say it is possible to use shorter strings, what do you mean exactly? What do you think about the idea of using `concatenatedWords.find(randomWord)` to look if a word already appears and if so don't add it to the concatenatedWords?

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. `aaaa` and `aaab` are the two first words you add, but that way `aaaa` occurs 3 times in the string already. It could have been just `aaaab`. What you suggest is certainly a good idea. Test it to see if it reduces the number of calls of `sendMessage` on average. I also seem to  remember there is some theory on how to build the string without repetitions -- something with Gray code like sequences, but that would be stuff for a separate question.

Comment: i tried using `concatenatedWords.find(randomWord)` and it works but it just takes so much performance. From a maximum of 0.015 seconds to a maximum of 2.1 seconds. Do you have any source where i can read something about building the string without repetitions?

Comment: It is described in [Wikipedia - De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence)